# Help with regexp replacing every second comma in the string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string of that displays like this....

1235, 3, 1343, 5, 1234, 1

I need to replace every second comma with a semicolon

i.e.

1235, 3; 1343, 5; 1234, 1

the string length will always be different but will follow the same pattern as the above i.e. digits comma space digits comma space, etc.

how can I do this with javascript? Is it possible?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Thank you all very much, I have learned quite a bit from these examples.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
'1235, 3, 1343, 5, 1234, 1'.replace(/([0-9]+),\s([0-9]+),\s/g, '$1, $2; ')
```

Comment: If you want to confirm correctness quickly try pasting into your browser's URL:

   javascript:alert('1235, 3, 1343, 5, 1234, 1'.replace(/([0-9]+),\s([0-9]+),\s/g, '$1, $2; '))

Answer (score 7):

```
var s = '1235, 3, 1343, 5, 1234, 1';
var result = s.replace(/(,[^,]*),/g,"$1;");
```

Comment: It's a valid tactic Dmitri - not sure what you mean

Answer (score 4):

```
var s='1235, 3, 1343, 5, 1234, 1';

s=s.replace(/([^,]+,[^,]+),/g,'$1;')
```

match anything that is not a comma, followed by a comma,
followed by anything that is not a comma, and a comma.

replace everthing inside the parens (which doesn't include the last comma) with itself ('$1'), and add a semicolon in place of that comma.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
var regex = /(\d+),\s(\d+),\s/g;
var str = '1235, 3, 1343, 5, 1234, 1'; 
alert(str.replace(regex, '$1, $2; ')); // 1235, 3; 1343, 5; 1234, 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var myregexp = /(\d+,\s\d+),/g;
result = subject.replace(myregexp, "$1;");
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var foo = "1235,3,1343,5,1234,1".replace(/(.\*?),(.\*?),/g, "$1,$2;");

console.log(foo)
```

Comment: Removed downvote after edit, (.*?) is the nongreedy match right? So it basically means [^,] here