# Replace the every 3rd comma in a string

Tags: javascript, string

So it I have the string:

```
var str = "blue,red,green,orange,yellow,brown,black,teal,purple,gold,silver"
```

How would you replace every 3rd comma with an `!` (For example)? It would look something like:

```
var str = "blue,red,green!orange,yellow,brown!black,teal,purple!gold,silver,white"
```

After scrapping together some things I found, I came up with this:

```
var str = "blue,red,green,orange,yellow,brown,black,teal,purple,gold,silver"

function replaceIndex(string, at, repl) {
   return string.replace(/\S/g, function(match, u) {
        if( u === at ) return repl;

        return match;
});

var total_items = str.split(",").length - 1;
var counter = 1;
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    if (str.charAt(i) == ","){
        if (total_items%counter == 0){
            replaceIndex(str, i, "},{");
        }
    counter++;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889408/help-with-regexp-replacing-every-second-comma-in-the-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with some regex magic:

```
str = str.replace(/([^,],[^,]*?,[^,]*?),/g, '$1!');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var str = "blue,red,green,orange,yellow,brown,black,teal,purple,gold,silver"
str = str.replace(/(([^,]*,){2}([^,]*)),/g, '$1!')
```